# I have a bunch of divs with a button in each, calling the same function, how do i know which div the button belongs to?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <script>
        function buttonfunction(){
            //todo things
        }
    </script>
        <div id="parentdiv">
            <div>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <button onclick="buttonfunction()" > clickme </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <button onclick="buttonfunction()" > clickme </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <p>info</p>
                <button onclick="buttonfunction()" > clickme </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the structure of my code, how do i get the info for the respective div from which the button is pressed from ?

these divs will be later dynamically added by javascript and there's no limit to the no if divs that can be added.

Comment: Look into using jQuery. Specifically the parent and child functionality. You will be able to pull the info from the <p> tags using parent and child functions possibly coupled with the find and next functions as well.

Comment: If they're unique, give the buttons an ID, and run a global click listener. Event.target.id should return for ex. Help, Signup, Register. If ID is already assigned give them a unique attribute like element.setAttribute("click-action","homepage"); and get it later with getAttribute("click-action");

Comment: If you run a listener on #parentdiv it should be able to on the event property detect these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use onclick attributes, they have some annoying gotchas and make it harder to solve this problem.
2. Add a delegated event listener and check that the element clicked is a button
3. Given that it is, search up the DOM to find the associated div

For the sake of this example, I've given the divs IDs to log, but you can do whatever you like with the div element. You don't need to assign an ID.

```js
const eventListener = event => {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "button") return;
    const div = target.parentNode;
    console.log(div.id);
};

addEventListener('click', eventListener);
```

```html
<div id="one"><button>Click me</button></div>
<div id="two"><button>Click me</button></div>
<div id="three"><button>Click me</button></div>
```